Ratio of infinite derivatives of analytic function
For a given analytic function $f(z)$, does the following hold true
If
$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d^{n+a}f(z)}{dx^{n+a}}=P$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{d^{n+b}f(z)}{dx^{n+b}}=Q$ where a,b are integers
Can it be implied that $P/Q=1$?
I understand that some analytic functions like sin(z), cos(z) the infinite derivative will be undefined because the derivatives oscillate back to the initial function. What about the functions whose derivatives are not cyclic in nature?

$P/Q=1$ is equivalent to $P=Q,$ but covers the additional case $Q=0.$ Why write it as a fraction?

This is more generally true. If $c_n$ is a sequence, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_{n+a}=P$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_{n+b}=P$ for any $b.$ It has nothing to do with derivatives

Didn't think infinite derivative can equal to 0. P=Q is also an equivalent statement.

Infinite derivatives are not a thing, of course. But if $f(x)=\sum_n\frac{x^n}{2^{n!}}$ then for each $x,$ the limit of the derivatives is zero.

P and Q are analytic functions too.

But can they be said to be equal analytic function?

I would say the infinite derivative doesn't make any sense. Think of it in terms of units. If the units of $x$ is seconds, and $f(x)$ is meters, the unit of the nth derivative is $m/s^n.$ So there is no sense that the limit makes sense as the units are not compatible. It is really wrong to talk about infinite derivatives - they rarely exist, and when the limit it does exist, it is doesn't really mean anything

@Sidharth. Note that infinite-order derivatives may vanish (e.g. all polynomial functions), but usually they don't exist $-$ because they are undefined or divergent $-$, even if one deals with an analytic function. Indeed, consider for instance the following basic case :
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} e^{\lambda x} =
\begin{cases}
0       & \text{if}; -1 < \lambda < 1 \
e^x   & \text{if}; \lambda = 1 \
\infty & \text{if}; \lambda > 1
\end{cases},
$$
while it is both divergent and undefined (because of an alternating sign) when $\lambda < -1$.

I think you ask here 2 different things:  1. If $f_{n} (x)=f^{(n)}(x)$ and $f_n \to P(x)$ (converges uniformingly or pointwise) then $f_{n+k} (x)=f^{(n+k)}(x) \to P(x)$, This one is true,  And  2.  The "infinite derivative" that is not clear what you do mean by that...
